# why isn't a blank page inserted?

Tags: xetex, blank-page, textpos

Shouldn't the following code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\providecommand{\insertblankpage}[0]{ \newpage \leavevmode \thispagestyle{empty} \newpage }

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{4}[0,0](4.3,2.5)
\begin{center}
{\Large
Bla Bla\linebreak
some text
}
\end{center}
\end{textblock}
\insertblankpage

\end{document}
```

output a pdf (using XeLaTeX) with two pages? (one with some text and the other one blank).

Instead only one page is produced.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that the textblock isn't in the page flow it os added at shipout to the page, nut only once there is a page to add. So basically you need to generate two blank pages, one to carry the textblock and one really blank.

```
 \providecommand{\insertblankpage}[0]{ \mbox{}\clearpage  \leavevmode  \thispagestyle{empty} \newpage }
```

Comment: Thank you, I've checked this and it works. But its obvious you were... in a rush! If you like please make it more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: I was watching the olympics:-)